# Python speed up dataframe writes

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm aware that iterating frames in pandas is a very slow operation.  I've heard vectorization speeds things up. I found a project that I'm using for sentiment analysis on reddit.

[The Calculate dataframe method](https://github.com/GonVas/tickerrain/blob/1c701f82353c5d4d7299c5edff1db5da5fa71eaf/process.py#L103) wasn't working for some reason, (maybe different version of panda) I wanted to refactor it to use vectorization but Sadly it took me 2 days to even get the code working.

```
def calculate_df(df):
    data_df = df.filter(['tickers', 'score', 'sentiment'])
    
    tickers_processed = pd.DataFrame(df.tickers.explode().value_counts())
    
    tickers_processed = tickers_processed.rename(columns = {'tickers':'counts'})
    
    tickers_processed['score'] = 0.0
    tickers_processed['sentiment'] = 0.0
    
    for idx, row_tick in enumerate(tickers_processed.itertuples(), 1):
        upd_row_sent = row_tick.sentiment
        upd_row_score = row_tick.score
        for row_data in data_df.itertuples():
            if(row_tick.Index in row_data.tickers):
                upd_row_sent += row_data.sentiment['compound'] / row_tick.counts
                upd_row_score += int(row_data.score) / row_tick.counts
                tickers_processed.set_value(row_tick.Index, 'sentiment', upd_row_sent)
                tickers_processed.set_value(row_tick.Index, 'score', upd_row_score)
```

Calling set value twice seems redundant,  If I could calculate the dataset and update it using vectors I think the code would be a lot nicer

Comment: Welcome to posting to CodeReview@SE at long last. I can't identify `The Calculate dataframe method` - am I missing something?

Comment: @greybeard sorry the code is the contents of the method, ive updated to provide a link to the original code, this is the only portion I would like to refactor

Comment: I edited the method "def line" into your post mainly to show you *can* copy&paste between CR post & (I)DE. I urge you to include the code following that from *process.py*, I'd probably choose a separate code block to tell *supposed* target from [*context*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I can include more code, but I mostly just wanted to fix the double for loop, to leverage vertorization, I didn't want to include anything extra to confuse the reviewers

Comment: (Reads like you didn't follow the above hyperlink to *How do I ask a Good Question?*)

Comment: I don't see what i'm missing, the refactor is related to the inner contents of the code only.  I've explain what I think is the issue and how it can be fixed.  The column names can be easily inferred from the code.  So what good would posting unrelated code be to the question,  When the only thing that needs to be removed here is the forloops to use vectorization?

Comment: I can almost guarantee you will get answer quickly if you post a full working example. It's quite tedious to verify what your code does, and to make sure you don't break any logic unless you have a small toy dataset to play around with. This will also make it easy to measure performance.

Comment: @Juho the link in the post provides the full code in, usually I feel like people avoid posts with code dumps,  but seeing as this has now been told to me by multiple people I have a feeling I don't understand this community as well as I do Stackoverflow.  I'll edit it when I get a chance